# Анимация для input внутри label

Tags: html, css, css-animation, checkbox

`input` и `label` объединены через атрибут `for`. При выборе, происходит анимация и появляется галка. Нет проблем.

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}

label {
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

label::before {
    color: white;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    left: -5px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 28px;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    transform: scale(0);
}

label img {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

:checked+label {
    border-color: #ddd;
}

:checked+label::before {
    content: "✓";
    background-color: #007bff;
    transform: scale(1);
    z-index: 1;
}

:checked+label img {
    transform: scale(0.9);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #333;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <input type="checkbox" data-index="1" id="id">    
  <label for="id">
    <img class="card-playlist-cover card-img-top" src="https://sun1-23.userapi.com/impf/c639325/v639325774/5894a/8OswStnRDhI.jpg?size=300x300&amp;quality=96&amp;proxy=1&amp;sign=c1512d2e4d19c04eea49447fc0151e47&amp;c_uniq_tag=jt8OErG6NqqwrBQMzq5hih_0eL3-7jb83jlzgYvZs50&amp;type=audio" alt="Said The Sky">
    <div class="m-2">
      <div class="text-truncate">Said The Sky</div><small class="text-muted">Треков: 37</small>
    </div>
  </label></div>
```

Хочу поместить `input` внутрь `label` и удалить `for`. Но не удается перенести анимацию. Галка не появляется. В чем причина?

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}

label {
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

label::before {
    color: white;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    left: -5px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 28px;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    transform: scale(0);
}

label img {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

label > :checked {
    border-color: #ddd;
}

label::before > :checked {
    content: "✓";
    background-color: #007bff;
    transform: scale(1);
    z-index: 1;
}

label > :checked + img {
    transform: scale(0.9);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #333;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="card"> 
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-index="1">   
    <img class="card-playlist-cover card-img-top" src="https://sun1-23.userapi.com/impf/c639325/v639325774/5894a/8OswStnRDhI.jpg?size=300x300&amp;quality=96&amp;proxy=1&amp;sign=c1512d2e4d19c04eea49447fc0151e47&amp;c_uniq_tag=jt8OErG6NqqwrBQMzq5hih_0eL3-7jb83jlzgYvZs50&amp;type=audio" alt="Said The Sky">
    <div class="m-2">
      <div class="text-truncate">Said The Sky</div><small class="text-muted">Треков: 37</small>
    </div>
  </label></div>
```

Comment: Селектор `label::before > :checked` ошибочный. В псевдоэлементе `:before` нет чекбокса. А если бы и был, то данный селектор бы на чекбокс дейстовал. Прошлый вариант работал из-за плюса в селекторе. Здесь вам тоже нужно сделать какой-то элемент после чекбокса, на который подействует плюс или тильда.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Удалось перенести анимацию и галку. Спасибо комментарию.

```css
input[type='checkbox'] {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}

label {
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.flag-check::before {
    color: white;
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    left: -5px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 28px;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transform: scale(0);
}

label img {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

:checked ~ .flag-check::before  {
    content: "✓";
    background-color: #007bff;
    transform: scale(1);
    z-index: 20;
}

label > :checked + img {
    transform: scale(0.9);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #333;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">   
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-index="1"> 
    <img class="card-playlist-cover card-img-top" src="https://sun1-23.userapi.com/impf/c639325/v639325774/5894a/8OswStnRDhI.jpg?size=300x300&amp;quality=96&amp;proxy=1&amp;sign=c1512d2e4d19c04eea49447fc0151e47&amp;c_uniq_tag=jt8OErG6NqqwrBQMzq5hih_0eL3-7jb83jlzgYvZs50&amp;type=audio" alt="Said The Sky">
    <div class="flag-check m-2">
      <div class="text-truncate">Said The Sky</div><small class="text-muted">Треков: 37</small>
    </div>
  </label></div>
```